# IntelliJ Error:Abnormal build process termination

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

I've just installed IntelliJ and I am trying to build a Scala project. However, every time I do, I get this error message:

> Information:6/7/16, 12:14 PM - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 10ms
>       Error:Abnormal build process termination: 
>       /Users/USERNAME/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs=\"\" -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Dpreload.project.path=/Users/USERNAME/IdeaProjects/Test -Dpreload.config.path=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2016.1/options -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=2119707358466010108 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djps.file.types.component.name=CommunityFileTypes -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2016.1 "-Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents" -Didea.config.path=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Preferences/IdeaIC2016.1 "-Didea.plugins.path=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1" -Djps.log.dir=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Logs/IdeaIC2016.1/build-log -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2016.1/compile-server/*temp* -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/var/folders/47/hxl33m1103l7fr2cqgpzt6wwhy3pcc/T/kotlin-idea-8457166580963725031-is-running\" -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_91/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.5.2.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/netty-all-4.1.0.CR7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jgoodies-forms.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/picocontainer.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/snappy-in-java-0.3.1.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jsr166e.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jna-platform.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/asm-all.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/trove4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-builders.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/log4j.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jna.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/resources_en.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/openapi.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jdom.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/forms_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/oromatcher.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-model.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/protobuf-2.5.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/javac2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/nanoxml-2.2.3.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/rt/jps-plugin-system.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/commons-io-1.4.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-groovy-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-cli-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-core-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-model-groovy-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-resources-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-api.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-extension-impl.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-2.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/jna-3.2.7.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/jsr305-1.3.9.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/kryo-2.22.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-amd64-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-freebsd-i386-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-linux-i386-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-amd64-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-osx-i386-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-amd64-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/native-platform-windows-i386-0.10.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/reflectasm-1.07.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/resources_en.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/gson-2.5.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/ui-designer-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/IntelliLang/lib/intellilang-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-rt-constants.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/common-eclipse-util.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/lib/plexus-utils-2.0.6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/jps/android-gradle-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/android-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/sdk-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/sdklib.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/jarutils.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/layoutlib-api.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/manifest-merger.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/scala-library.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/compiler-settings.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/jps/nailgun.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/jps/scala-jps-plugin.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/jps/sbt-interface.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/jps/incremental-compiler.jar:/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/IdeaIC2016.1/Scala/lib/jps/jline.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/lib/kotlin-android-extensions-compiler-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/common-javaFX-plugin.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49375 a775f585-9448-4991-83ab-e8b1c1596ad5 /Users/USERNAME/Library/Caches/IdeaIC2016.1/compile-server

Comment: That's not an error message but (part of) a command line Please post the actual error.

Comment: I feel like such an idiot, but where would I find the actual error?

Comment: I have no idea. You're the one telling us you get an error message! What else happens? Does the project build? What's at the end of the message you truncated?

Comment: The project does not build. All I get is an "Error: Abnormal build process termination:" followed by that long command line.

Comment: Then I think you need to post all of the message. There may be an error somewhere in there.

Comment: OK. I've edited and put in the entire message. Thanks.

Comment: Still can't see any error message. Does IntelliJ have logs? Or can you start with a debug option? My responses, if any, wlll be delayed - hopefully others can help.

Comment: Thanks. It was just a jdk problem. All set.

Comment: Can you post an answer and elaborate on it being "a jdk problem"? I'm having this exact same error and would love to know how you solved it!

Comment: I'm really trying to remember what I did. I think it ended up being a problem with where the jdk was located. Go to File -> Project Structure. Then, on the side, under Platform Settings select SDK's. Make sure that the one you have set up is in fact the right jdk. If not, click the green plus button, and select the path to where your idk is downloaded. Hope this helps. Sorry I can't remember so well.

Comment: @WillBuck have you added any external library to your CLASSPATH variable?

Comment: @user5407287 have you added any external library or jar archive to your CLASSPATH variable? or modified the calss path under the JDK inside Intellij?

Comment: @7kemZmani not that I know of?

Comment: I found my issue! In IntelliJ Preferences, Under "Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler", I had set the box labeled "Build Process heap size" to 700, and "Shared build process VM options" to "-Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512m", thinking the first box was unrelated / would be overridden by my VM options. Not the case. I just had Min Heap > Max Heap. Fixed now >_>

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me when I updated Nvidia drivers to 378.49. After reinstalling JDK and rolling back to oldest versions as 368.81(which didn't work), I just rolled back right to the previous 376.33 and it worked.

Comment: Wow! I just wonder what Nvidia driver had to do with InteliJ, Java or Scala.

Comment: Nvidia driver version 378.66 resolves above issue... they fixed it, you can see changelog here http://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/378.66/378.66-win10-win8-win7-desktop-release-notes.pdf

Comment: Works for me! Same situation... just update to 378.66 and all works.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with the Nvidia drivers 378.49.  As soon as I installed them, I started getting this error.  After rolling back to 376.33 it started working without even having to reboot or restart IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

Ok, not sure if that will help you but it solved problem form me, I had the same problem with my Java projects after I update to Intellij 16
basically a had to remove JDK from machine and install it again.

Comment: I still have the same problem :( I still can't believe I will have to rollback Nvidia driver update... this is ridiculous :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the NVIDIA graphics driver. I had the same problem, I tried formatting my PC but still had the same problem. But when I formatted I first installed my grahpics card and IntelliJ, and when i uninstalled my Nvidia driver ... IntelliJ worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, checking for update and upgrading to the newer version of IntelliJ solved the issue.